# How to call multiple sp using php in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, stored-procedures

**FOR EG**

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results('CALL p1()'); 
print_r($result);
$res = $wpdb->get_results('CALL p2()'); 
print_r($res);
```

This shows only the result of procedure p1()

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$wpdb->last_result ()
```

instead of

```
$wpdb->get_results()
```